# Jquery Datatable Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have created a datatable using jquery which is as below:
This table has 6 columns. First column is checkbox while the last column has textbox.

```
$('#multiple-account-table').dataTable({
        "data": [
            {"accountNumber":"131-202553701","name":"Account 1","dueDate":"10/19/2016","statementBalance":"34.60"},
            {"accountNumber":"131-202553702","name":"Account 2","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"14.50"},
            {"accountNumber":"131-202553703","name":"Account 3","dueDate":"10/19/2015","statementBalance":"15.50"}
            ],
        "dom": 'it',
        "pageLength": 8,
        "language": {
            "info": "_END_ of _TOTAL_ selected",
            "emptyTable": "No records are available",
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": null},
            {"data": "accountNumber"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "dueDate"},
            {"data": "statementBalance"},
            {"data": null}

        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10 white-active-bg mouse-link", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5]},
            {
                 'targets':   0,
                 'orderable': false,
                 'render': function(data, type, full, meta) {
                         return '<input type="checkbox" name="payment-checkbox" class="multi-checkbox"/>';
                 }
            },
            {
                'targets': 3,
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).text(date);
              }
             },
            {
                'targets': 4,
                'orderable': false,
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html('$'+sData);
                }
             },
             {
                'targets': 5,
                'searchable':false,
                'orderable':false,
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    $(nTd).html('<span class="bold">Payment Amount</span> <span class="dollar-font-xs">$<input type="number" id="payement-textbox-xs'+index_xs+'" class="payment-xs" min="0" max="100000" step="any" maxlength="9" value="" name="payment-textbox" placeholder="--"/></span>');

                }
             }
            ],
        "aaSorting": [[3, 'desc'], , [4,'asc'] ],

    }); //End of datatable function
```

And I am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Any suggestion?

Comment: Show the error itself. So we know where it is happening.

Comment: Replace `"aaSorting": [[3, 'desc'], , [4,'asc'] ],` with `"aaSorting": [[3, 'desc'], [4,'asc'] ]`. There are couple extra commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line, is it so in your code?

```
"aaSorting": [[3, 'desc'], , [4,'asc'] ],
```